# Efficient way to call previous row in python

Tags: python, optimization

I want to substitute the previous row value whenever a 0 value is found in the column of the dataframe in python. I used the following code,

```
 if not a[j]:
     a[j] = a[j-1]
```

and also

```
if a[j]==0:
    a[j]=a[j-1]
```

Update:

Complete code updated:

```
for i in pd.unique(r.a):
    sub=r[r.vehicle_id==i]
    sub=DataFrame(sub,columns=  ['a','b','c','d','e'])
    sub=sub.drop_duplicates(["a","b","c","d"])
    sub['c']=pd.to_datetime(sub['c'],unit='s')

    for j in range(1, len(sub[1:])):

        if not sub.d[j]:
            sub.d[j] = sub.d[j-1]
        if not sub.e[j]:
            sub.e[j]=sub.e[j-1]

    sub=sub.drop_duplicates(["lash_angle","lash_check_count"])
```

This is the starting of my code. the sub.d[j] line is only getting delayed

These both seem to work well when using integer values. One of the column contains decimal values. When using the code for that column, it is taking a huge time to complete(Nearly 15-20 secs) for the statement to complete. I am looping through nearly 10000 ids and wasting 15 secs at this step is making my entire code inefficient. Is there a better way, I can do this for the float (decimal) values, so that it would be much faster?

Thanks

Comment: 15s to check if `a[j]==0`? That sounds unreasonable...

Comment: Show more. The problem is not in those lines.

Comment: In any case the test should be if abs(a[j]) <sys.float_info.epsilon or something along those lines for a floating point argument.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: @paisanco I am not getting what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "column of the dataframe" you mean you're actually talking about a column (Series) of a pandas DataFrame, then one trick is to replace the 0 by nan and then forward-fill.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4, 10**6))
>>> df.head(10)
   0
0  0
1  3
2  3
3  0
4  1
5  2
6  3
7  2
8  0
9  3
>>> df[0] = df[0].replace(0, np.nan).ffill()
>>> df.head(10)
    0
0 NaN
1   3
2   3
3   3
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   2
8   2
9   3
```

where you can decide for yourself how you want to handle the case of a 0 at the start, where you have no value to fill.  This assumes that there aren't already NaN values you want to leave alone, but if there are, you can just use a mask with `.loc` to select only the ones you want to change.